# Jpa Specification Generic type class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, specifications

I'm currently building a advance search for a project using Specifications and Criteria Builder, I have multiple entities that I would like to create a generic class Specification builder. My question, is it possible to do it?

Entity example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "marcas")
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "tipo_marca")
    private Brandtype brandtype;
    @Column(name = "fecha_creacion")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    @Column(name = "fecha_actalizacion")
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "brand",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<Bike> bikes;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "brand",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<Model> models;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "brand",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<Accesorie> accesories;

    public Brand() {
    }

    public Brand(Integer id, String name, Brandtype brandtype) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.brandtype = brandtype;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Brandtype getBrandtype() {
        return brandtype;
    }

    public void setBrandtype(Brandtype brandtype) {
        this.brandtype = brandtype;
    }

    public Set<Bike> getBikes() {
        return bikes;
    }

    public void setBikes(Set<Bike> bikes) {
        this.bikes = bikes;
    }

    public Set<Model> getModels() {
        return models;
    }

    public void setModels(Set<Model> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    public Set<Accesorie> getAccesories() {
        return accesories;
    }

    public void setAccesories(Set<Accesorie> accesories) {
        this.accesories = accesories;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void beforeCreate(){
        this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeUpdate(){
        this.updateDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brand{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", brandtype=" + brandtype+
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Brand brand = (Brand) o;
        return id.equals(brand.id) && name.equals(brand.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }
}
```

Reposotory example

```
@Repository
public interface BrandRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository <Brand, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Brand> {

}
```

Search Criteria class:

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;

    public SearchCriteria() {
    }

    public SearchCriteria(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And this is the class Specification:

```
public class BrandSpecification implements Specification<Brand>{

    private SearchCriteria criteria;

    public BrandSpecification(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        this.criteria = searchCriteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Brand> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
            
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());

        }
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
            return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        }
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return builder.like(
                        root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public SearchCriteria getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }

    public void setCriteria(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }
}
```

I want to convert to generic so I can re use the code and dont need to rewrite it multiple times, can I have something like: `public class GenericSpecification implements Specification<E>{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
public class AppSpecification<T> implements Specification<T>{

private SearchCriteria criteria;

public AppSpecification(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    this.criteria = searchCriteria;
}

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {

        return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                root.<T> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());

    }
    else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
        return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                root.<T> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
    }
    else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
        if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
            return builder.like(
                    root.<T>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
        } else {
            return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then you can initiate the class as follows:

```
var brandSpecification = new AppSpecification<Brand>(searchCriteria);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank U so much it worked preatty good I'll love to up vote your answer but I don't have the rep to do so.